# Mysqli prepared statement not fetching correct value in each for loop post

Tags: php, for-loop, mysqli, prepared-statement

I cannot fetch the proper field value for each post using the id I obtained from stripping the link in an rss feed.

MyBB rss feed does not provide the author value in rss feed so I am manually fetching it using the link found in the feed that contains the thread Id. I think I am successfully in getting the correct thread id from the link because I can echo the correct thread id in each post. Because of this, I use the same variable for the thread id in fetching for the author field (username) in my database. I am fetching the username field but it appears same for all the posts, it is actually the last username who posted. I was able to make this properly working, fetching the correct author but because of some crazy things in life and I am really a newbie in this field I was not able to back up and forgot how I did it.

This is the code I use to make the post from the feed:

```
            <?php

                //Getting RSS Feed
                $rss = new DOMDocument();
                $rss->load('https://www.cmricths.com/board/syndication.php?fid=2');
                $feed = array();

                foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
                    $item = array ( 
                        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('encoded')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                        );
                    array_push($feed, $item);
                }

                //Setting Feed Limits
                $fid = 2;
                $limit = 5;

                require_once 'queries/threadcount.php';

                if ($tcount > $limit) {
                    $tlimit = $limit;
                } else {
                    $tlimit = $tcount;
                }

                //Posting the feed
                for($x=0;$x<$tlimit;$x++) {

                    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
                    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
                    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
                    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));

                    //getting thread id from the link
                    $arr = explode('=', $link);
                    $tid = $arr[1];

                    //fetching the author
                    require_once 'queries/postedby.php';

                    //post summary
                    echo '<h2 class="blog-post-title">'.$title.'</h2>';
                    echo '<p class="blog-post-meta">'.$date.' <em>by: '.$author.' '.$tid.'</em></p>';
                    echo '<p class="mb-0">'.$description.'</p>';
                    echo '<hr />';

                }

            ?>
```

This is the code for fetching the author:

```
<?php
/*

References: 
*jQuery Remote Validation
*https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

*/

// Get Connection Details
require_once 'config.php';

// Setup the connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if($mysqli->connect_error) {

    echo json_encode('Error connecting to database!');
    exit;

} else {

    // Do the validation process
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8mb4");

    //Prepare the statement
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `username` FROM `mybb_posts` WHERE `tid` = ?");

    //Bind the parameter
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $tid);

    //Execute the statement
    $stmt->execute();

    //Get the result
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    //Fetch Data
    $row = $result->fetch_array();

    $author = $row['username'];

}


?>
```

This is my sql data file:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for mybb_posts
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mybb_posts`;
CREATE TABLE `mybb_posts`  (
  `pid` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tid` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `replyto` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `fid` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `subject` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `icon` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `uid` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `username` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `dateline` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `message` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `ipaddress` varbinary(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `includesig` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `smilieoff` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `edituid` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `edittime` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `editreason` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `tid`(`tid`, `uid`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `uid`(`uid`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `visible`(`visible`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `dateline`(`dateline`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `ipaddress`(`ipaddress`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `tiddate`(`tid`, `dateline`) USING BTREE,
  FULLTEXT INDEX `message`(`message`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT = 12 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of mybb_posts
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `mybb_posts` VALUES (7, 6, 0, 2, 'Embed Imgur Album Enabled', 0, 1, 'jodilljames.esteban', 1558864524, 'Imgur Album Embed Test\r\n\r\n[imgur]a/b04h89n[/imgur]\r\n\r\nThe quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. :D', 0xA29E76CA, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 1);
INSERT INTO `mybb_posts` VALUES (10, 9, 0, 2, 'Video Embed Test', 0, 1, 'jodilljames.esteban', 1558960466, '[video=youtube]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=in-2VHDv44Q[/video]', 0xA29E7612, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 1);
INSERT INTO `mybb_posts` VALUES (11, 10, 0, 2, 'WELCOME MESSAGE FOR SCHOOL YEAR 2019-2020!', 0, 5, 'hermes.vargas', 1559018673, 'The school year 2019-2020 has just started. New friends, new classmates, new teachers, new challenges and new learnings are bound to happen. The journey to success will never easy, as the saying goes, \"the journey of a thousand miles begins with a single step!\" In order to succeed this school year, bear these three (3) important reminders. First, have an open mind to learning. As a student, you learn  knowledge, acquire skills and develop values. Let your mind accept these positivities to make you better. Second, have a loving heart. Respect emanates from love. Let your love for God, country, environment and fellow men overflow in each day. There is no room for chaos in our school And third, have a disciplined soul. Your intelligence is futile without discipline. A disciplined learner will go beyond the borders of success. As I end let me tell you this quote from Eleanor D. Roosevelt, \"the future belongs to those who believe in the beauty of their dreams!\"\r\n\r\n[b]HERMES PACATANG VARGAS, LPT[/b]\r\nPrincipal II', 0xA29E7711, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 1);
INSERT INTO `mybb_posts` VALUES (6, 5, 0, 7, 'Hello World', 0, 0, 'TheRandomPoster', 1558861460, 'I just wanted you to know that this post is moderated...\r\n\r\nHello Folks!!! :cool:', 0xA29E7604, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 1);
INSERT INTO `mybb_posts` VALUES (8, 7, 0, 17, 'Forum Membership', 11, 1, 'jodilljames.esteban', 1558869862, '[b][color=#3333ff]Welcome to Claro M. Recto ICT High School Forum Board![/color][/b]\r\n\r\nThis is board is exclusive only for the Faculty, School Club Officers and selected personnel. \r\n\r\nTo request membership access please seek for CMRICTHS ICT Devs: \r\n\r\n[list]\r\n[*][b]Randy A. Rosales[/b]\r\n[*][b]Jun S. Tibay[/b]\r\n[*][b]Maria Mia Soriano[/b]\r\n[*][b]Jodill James A. Esteban[/b]\r\n[/list]\r\n\r\nNon members can still participate and post message threads in our Public Forum ([url=https://www.cmricths.com/board/forumdisplay.php?fid=7]Click Here[/url]). \r\n\r\nThanks.', 0xA29E761E, 0, 0, 0, 0, '', 1);

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

I am suppose to be getting the correct author for each thread. So if the thread id is 9 I should be getting jodilljames.esteban as the author and if the thread id is 10 I should be getting hermes.vargas as the author and so on...

Comment: `require_once` in a loop isn't going to do what you want it to.

Comment: Thank you very much @Phil, it was the require_once's fault, i changed it to just require and it is working perfectly. This is the best answer. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you take some of the code from the `queries/postedby.php` script and put it at the start of your code, create the `prepared statement` before you begin any loops then you might find  an approach like the following works.

That said I'm surprised the PHPBB does not allow editing of the RSS to the extent where you can select what is added to the feed... Maybe it does - maybe it doesn't - it's years since I looked at that software.

goodluck, hope it helps a little

```
<?php
    /*
        Create the db connection and build your prepared statement

    */
    require_once 'config.php';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare( "SELECT `username` FROM `mybb_posts` WHERE `tid` = ?" );


    if( $stmt ){
        /*
            If the statement was constructed OK then bind a variable to
            the placeholder in the sql statement. This variable will be
            deduced later...
        */
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $tid );




        $rss = new DOMDocument();
        $rss->load('https://www.cmricths.com/board/syndication.php?fid=2');
        $feed = array();

        foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
            $item = array ( 
                'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('encoded')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            );
            array_push($feed, $item);
        }

        //Setting Feed Limits
        $fid = 2;
        $limit = 5;




        /*
            It is unknown what is in this file - if it contains
            a db connection then I'd suggest editing it to 
            remove the db connection as one already exists in
            this page/script....
        */
        require_once 'queries/threadcount.php';

        if ($tcount > $limit) {
            $tlimit = $limit;
        } else {
            $tlimit = $tcount;
        }

        //Posting the feed
        for($x=0;$x<$tlimit;$x++) {

            $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
            $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
            $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
            $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));

            //getting thread id from the link
            $arr = explode('=', $link);
            $tid = $arr[1];



            /*

                query db &
                fetch result

            */
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            $row = $result->fetch_array();
            $author = $row['username'];
            $stmt->free_result();



            //post summary
            echo '<h2 class="blog-post-title">'.$title.'</h2>';
            echo '<p class="blog-post-meta">'.$date.' <em>by: '.$author.' '.$tid.'</em></p>';
            echo '<p class="mb-0">'.$description.'</p>';
            echo '<hr />';

        }
    } else {
        exit( 'error' );
    }


    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ram, i got it already working with using require instead of require_once. Although i would like to point out that i am using MyBB rss not PHPBB, i think they are different. It's a mybb problem as stated here: https://community.mybb.com/thread-221222.html, i am just looking for some work around, and now it's working :)